# Missing $ inserted. Extra }, or forgotten $ in verbatim

Tags: latex, xelatex

I am rendering inline math in verbatim environment.

The code for which is

```
\usepackage{upquote} % Upright quotes for verbatim code
\usepackage{eurosym} % defines \euro
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Extended unicode (utf-8) support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Allow utf-8 characters in the tex document
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % verbatim replacement that allows latex

\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, fontsize=\small, xleftmargin=-3.9em]
\displaystyle \cos{\left(x \right)}  - (1)
\end{Verbatim} - (2)
```

For line (1), Warning is - Missing $ inserted. Extra }, or forgotten $ .

For line (2), Warning is - Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. Missing $ inserted. Missing } inserted .

If anyone wants to see this live, here is the overleaf link(read only) :- https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvrbkmkmdcgc

I am not able to figure out the correct syntax needed here.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] instead of code fragments?

Comment: @samcarter Done the edit in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add math mode around your inline math. In normal text you would probably use `$...$`, but as you already have enabled `\` to be escaped as the start of a latex command, you can use `\(....\)` as a quick workaround. If you need more flexibility, I suggest to have a look into the `listings` package instead of `fancyvrb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote} % Upright quotes for verbatim code
\usepackage{eurosym} % defines \euro
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Extended unicode (utf-8) support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Allow utf-8 characters in the tex document
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % verbatim replacement that allows latex
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}

\title{Testing}
\author{aakashguptachoudhury }
\date{October 2019}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}
 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, fontsize=\small, xleftmargin=-3.9em]
 \(\displaystyle \displaystyle \cos{\left(x\right)} \)
\end{Verbatim}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked. Though, had one more question if you can make something out of the error - 

! Illegal math \discretionary.

\FV@Space ...terbreak } {\kern \fontdimen 2\font }

                                                  
l.781 ...{outcolor}4}]:} \(\displaystyle 3 x + y\)

what math \discretionary should be used ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Aakash Without seeing the code that produces the problem it is hard to tell. maybe it would be best to ask a new question?